# Java: manage multiple processes simultaneously

Tags: java, multithreading

So I'm currently trying to create an application that will allow me to start and stop different processes via a WebSocket connection to the java application.
I've got a class to manage each process like

```
public class ServerProgram {
    Process p;

    public void Start() {
        this.p = new Process(...);
    }

    public void Stop() {
        this.p.destroy();
    }
}
```

1. How can I manage multiple instances at the same time, so I can run multiple processes?
2. How can I monitor the process, so the thread which started the Server is able to know when the process has crashed?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think you can monitor the state of a process from a thread of another process. The only wait that comes into my mind is to share the state of the process in some file. When you start the process form your thread, assign a unique value to your new process. Then, your process will write to a file his state (imagine, all 5 seconds). On the other side (the satarter thread) you can read the "status file", if the process doesn't write to his file in more than 5 seconds (using my previous example time) something is wrong.

Comment: I think that's a good starting point, but i want to keep handling that in the memory, not in some files.

Comment: If you don't want to use files, you can use redirectOutput and redirectInput from ProcessBuilder class. Basically, you can redirect the output of the "child" process to his parent and without any file communicate between them (sort of a pipe). But, I'm not sure if it will work for more than one process

Comment: If you are asking "how can I have multiple things in an object oriented program" you need to learn the basics with a simpler project first.

Comment: This is a very broad and vague question. Consider adding more details and specifics, including what you've tried so far and what sort of issues you've run into, so you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *How can I manage multiple instances at the same time, so I can run multiple processes?*

   When you're doing multiple things at the same time in the same program/process, you use threads. So each of your `ServerProgram` instances should be run in a separate thread.

   Consider using an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) rather than directly constructing threads for each process.
2. *How can I monitor the process, so the thread which started the Server is able to know when the process has crashed?*

   This entirely depends on the program you're trying to monitor. You can use [`isAlive()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#isAlive--) to see if it's still running, and read the process' [stdout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream--) and [stderr](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream--). Beyond that your process could do any number of other things, such as write to log files or communicate with your Java process, if you configure it to do so.

Comment: Why would you need to use a dedicated thread to monitor a single process? Couldn't you use a single thread in the Java program to monitor N processes?

Answer (score -1):

I think you may want to use thread intead processor. Did you mean a java classe for Processor? In this case maybe you can store a list of processor

Comment: I'm not quite sure what exactly you are trying to say but I think this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: OP is (presumably) using the [`Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) class. Threads don't execute external processes.